# Detect library dependencies on Python code statically

Tags: python-3.x, import, static, dependencies

Is there any software that can detect import dependencies in my python 3.x code, without having to run the actual code? Also something that could detect import inside a function too not only in global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you thinking of creating a requirements file then pipreqs is great

https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/